# HTML5 pixel manipulation issues; canvas not reading my images (can't be online)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Trying Canvas pixel manipulation and it won't read my image just displays white screen. It works when I use fillRect but not reading from an image from the hard drive? What I'm trying to do is use the sprite to edit the image. I want to read off images.

```
count = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < 172000; ++i) {
  switch (i % 480) {
    case 240:
      count = count - 1918;
      break;
    case 0:
      count = count + 1918
      break;
  }
  var hold = 4 * i + count;
  var nn = (imageData.data[hold] >> 1) % 64;
  var mm = screen[i] * 8 + (imageData.data[hold + 1] >> 5);
  var hq = (imageData.data[hold + 1] % 18);
  var sq = 18 * (imageData.data[hold] % 2);
  var m = (RELUM[mm][nn] * 36 + hq + sq);
  //ading hue to luminance
  var value = (m % 216);
  //outpuutting color
  var r = imageData.data[4 * value];
  var g = imageData.data[4 * value + 1];
  var b = imageData.data[4 * value + 2];
  var a = imageData.data[4 * value + 3];
  //Little endian
  data[i] = (a << 24) |
    (b << 16) |
    (g << 8) |
    r;
}
```

Comment: You are likely experiencing domain issue. Look at the FileReader to load images from your local drive without experiencing cross domain issues

Answer (score 0):

in order for canvas to load an image it can't be on your harddrive, it must be on a server (local or otherwise) and it must be on the same domain or CORS enabled.

an easy work-around is to use a base64 image. use a site [like this one](https://www.base64-image.de/) to convert your image into a base65 string which you can use the same way you would use an image src url, and then it will load.

Comment: Are there any other html5 pixel manipulation that will let me use offline images